# facebook login dialog when no internet

Tags: android, facebook

I have a simple problem (maybe) with my code... I have a facebook button that will open the login dialog for the user, which works fine. but if there is no internet it'll take forever and I don't know how to timeout it... I've put it in a 'try' block, but it still takes way too long

this is the code for it

```
try{    

    facebook.authorize(this,new String[] {"publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access"}, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}

        });

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

any help will be highly appreciated

P.S. this applies for the post into facebook as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put in some logic to detect whether there is a network connection and if not, do something nice for your users like tell them you require one.  Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available) for more info.

Comment: that idea crossed my mind and this is what I have ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

     if(connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING  ) 
problem is this checks if there is connection, meaning if I'm on local wifi with no internet, again the program will be stuck

Comment: well you can always try to ping a site if this doesn't work but the connectivity service should do the job in most of the cases. there are still some that you just cant avoid... but usually people connected to wifi or mobile data network have an active connection.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced same issue, and you have 2 way to do:

1. Edit Util.java in facebook SDK, add 1 line like conn.setTimeout(xxx);
2. Upgrade to newest facebook SDK, now it have timeout mechanism.